# Is there a way to use C-C for copy and C-V for paste in emacs?

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, clipboard, elisp

I know about [cua-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode), but I'm specifically wanting to bind C-C and C-V (the uppercase versions) to be like the terminal in Gnome.  Is there any way to do this?  I tried this, but it gave me all kinds of errors (apparently, it doesn't like me binding something to C-c whether the C is lowercase or not):

```
(global-set-key "\C-C" 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
(global-set-key "\C-V" 'clipboard-yank)
```

Is there any other way to do this, or am I just going to have to use a prefix of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remap the whole dang keyboard if you like, recent emacs even have a menu and GUI to help you with this.

Problem is, C-C in particular is a prefix to a lot of other commands. Those would all end up needing to be attached to new key combinations. While your cut&paste habits may die hard, in the long run you may get more joy if you "submit" to Emacs' conventions rather than try to force them into line with Windows keystrokes.

Comment: It's not about sticking to windows habits.  It's more about being consistent with the Linux terminal and using fewer keystrokes.  But, if the answer is "there's no way to use C-C for this without remapping a lot of stuff", then I'll just use a prefix.  :-)

Comment: M-w / C-y is consisted with the "Linux terminal" (AKA readline). Which terminal uses C-c / C-v for copy/paste? I have never heard such terminal.

Comment: AFAIK, `C-C` (with capital C) is not a prefix of anything at all, so you should be able to rebind it to anything you like with little conflict (if any).

Comment: lol C-c for copy in terminal would be crazy, C-c sends a SIGINT signal.

Answer (score 2):

*"It's more about being consistent with the Linux terminal and using fewer keystrokes."*

My Linux terminal understands C-Insert as Copy and S-Insert as Paste (kill and yank, respectively).  Emacs also understands those (at least the more recent versions do), or can be easily made to understand them.  In fact, most applications understand them, along with S-Delete for Cut; I usually only have trouble at Web-2.0 sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
(global-set-key [?\C-\S-c] 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
(global-set-key [?\C-\S-v] 'clipboard-yank)
```

Of course, this won't work in a text-terminal since in that case Emacs will receive the exact same byte-sequence wen you press <kbd>C-c</kbd> as when you press <kbd>C-C</kbd>.